# Copy and Paste mouse shortcuts in Git Bash terminal in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, git-bash

The text cannot be **COPIED by double-clicking** and **PASTED on right-clicking** when working on **Git bash in Eclipse**, similar to the usage in Git Bash Windows application, which saves much time.

Is there any solution or best terminal alternative integrated in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be supported by the Terminal component, [part of CDT since Eclipse 2020-03](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn911#Release), with code source now in [`org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/terminal`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/terminal).

No issue has been mentioned in [this bugzilla list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?component=terminal&product=CDT&quicksearch=copy), which means you would need to create one to mention this use case.